# I'm new to web design - Will this system work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I started using Dreamweaver just some weeks ago and after some html and css test I started building my site. The web site is about alternative rock, so my idea is that it will have a page for every band on its database, where it'll show some info, some images, and the list of cds.

So I already built up the home page using HTML, CSS (duh) and a bit of Javascript for the header/footer and for random quotes.

The problem is that every band will have its own page in the site and doing them all manually is just insane, so I was thinking I could use some js to make a system that does it for me.

My idea is this: in the folder where the html and js files are saved, create another folder named "bands", then inside it, there will be a folder for every band the site will include; inside it, there will be that band's data, for example an .ini file with the cds info, some images, etc.

The last step is to create a new html page, when I create the format for the info to be shown, and then, depending on the visitor's choice, js enters the folder of the band he chose, reads the data, and shows it.

So, is this even doable or is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: you should look into content management systems

Comment: I like the creative thinking, but I concur with JLF and Stan that you are much better to look at a proper CMS or create a database system yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My idea is this: in the folder where the html and js files are saved, create another folder named "bands", then inside it, there will be a folder for every band the site will include; inside it, there will be that band's data, for example an .ini file with the cds info, some images, etc.

No, this is horrible idea. What you need is proper back-end with a database that will store info about every band.

This way you will be able to:

1. Create, edit, delete band pages on-the-fly using some kind of admin panel.
2. Not clutter your webserver with all the folders and html files
3. Don't do duplicate work for every band with your js and/or html files.

You should start by looking into some content-manager system, like Wordpress or Drupal. Or better yet - build a simple one yourself using any language you choose fit to. (That way you will actually learn how to deal with databases and write back-end code yourself)

Comment: thanks! I'll check that out